# Building Qt with external dependencies post the 5.8 build regression

Tags: qt, build, dependencies, regression, external

Now that the [regression, introduced with the new Qt build system in 5.8 is resolved](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-30083), how do specify external dependencies when building Qt?

Are we back to the old (bad) syntax that was removed in 5.8? Or is there a new way to do it?

Comment: What do you mean by "specifying external dependencies". This can mean anything to anyone... Please provide concrete examples of what you mean.

Comment: I mean providing libraries for stuff like sql, ssl and whatnot. See the bug and related issues.

Comment: Not sure I am getting you. The options were **removed** in 5.8 It wasn't a matter of "working incorrectly" it was a matter of "not having the option to specify 3rd party libs". Again - feel free to post an answer containing a configuration string that successfully specifies 3rd party libs to be used in the qt build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `configure -help`:

> Each uppercased library name (obtainable with `-list-libraries`) supports the
>   suffixes `_INCDIR`, `_LIBDIR`, `_PREFIX (INCDIR=PREFIX/include, LIBDIR=PREFIX/lib)`,
>   `_LIBS`, and - on Windows and Darwin - `_LIBS_DEBUG` and `_LIBS_RELEASE`. E.g.,
>   `ICU_PREFIX=/opt/icu42 ICU_LIBS="-licui18n -licuuc -licudata"`.

Thus:

1. `configure -list-libraries` to get the list of configurable libraries.
2. For each `FOO` from the above, provide:

   - `FOO_PREFIX` **or** both `FOO_LIBDIR` and `FOO_INCDIR`,
   - `FOO_LIBS` if not empty,
   - optionally `FOO_LIBS_DEBUG` and `FOO_LIBS_RELEASE` if there's a difference between the two variants (not optional if `FOO_LIBS` is empty).

E.g., to set up MYSQL, assuming `configure -list-libraries` includes MYSQL:

```
configure \
  MYSQL_INCDIR=E:\msys64\mingw64\include\mariadb \
  MYSQL_LIBDIR=E:\msys64\mingw64\lib \
  MYSQL_LIBS="-l mysqlclient"
```

Comment: Gonna be really specific here, prior ot 5.8 I configured via `-L E:\msys64\mingw64\lib -qt-sql-psql -qt-sql-mysql -l mysqlclient -I E:\msys64\mingw64\include\mariadb`, so how do we translate that to the "new and improved build system"?

Comment: I will give that a go with the latest dev branch. But I kinda wish those things were better documented and more straightforward. I mean it is not like every developer who uses Qt has his live revolving around it and its many quirks. Should it really be that awkward? I mean it looks like the "improved build system" is actually a huge step back, if we go from a "uniform way to include any lib" to a "specific way to include a particular on the odd chance support for it has been implemented"

Comment: They all are supposed to be implemented. The new build system is not a set back. It was released a bit too early, but it finally unifies Windows and non-Windows configuration, allows you to leverage the configuration tests in your own projects, and finally makes the Qt feature reduction work.

Comment: Finally found the time to try a test build using 5.9.1, still getting `ERROR: Feature 'sql-mysql' was enabled, but the pre-condition 'libs.mysql' failed`

Comment: OK, the issue was that I had `-static-runtime` as a configuration flag, in that case the build process fails to resolve any of the indirect dependencies of external libraries, mandating those be explicitly specified. The good news is by removing that flag I managed to get a successful config. Now lets see if the build will succeed too.